# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd1'

Tags: python, access, база-данных, запрос, sql

Написал следующий код

```
conAcc = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\ThirdTask\Northwind.accdb')
SqlAccess=conAcc.cursor();
SqlAccess.execute(sql.sql_count_record_clients);
CountOfRecords=SqlAccess.fetchone();
conAcc.close();
```

где в модуле sql.py есть строка

```
sql_count_records_clients='''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "Список клиентов"'''
```

В результате на эту строку в sql.py выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ThirdTask\connect.py", line 5, in <module>
    import json,sqlite3,sql
  File "D:\ThirdTask\sql.py", line 48
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd1' in file D:\ThirdTask\sql.py on line 48, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Что необходимо слелать, чтоб ошибка исчезла?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python 2.x по умолчанию читает исходники как ascii, и если видит октеты больше 127, то кричит вот этим самым `SyntaxError`.

Чтобы указать Python в какой кодировке записан файл, нужно в начало файла добавить специальный комментарий, подходящий под регэксп «`coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)`», как правило — одного из следующих видов:

```
# coding=<кодировка>
# -*- coding: <кодировка> -*-
# vim: set fileencoding=<кодировка> :
```

Где `<кодировка>` — собственно, кодировка, например, «utf-8» или «cp1251».

Подробно это описано в [PEP 263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Answer (score -1):

По опыту - в таких ситуациях обычно виновата кодировка БД…

Comment: @qnub , а при чем тут кодировка БД, если компилятор Python ругается на конкретную (мною приведенною) строку в модуле sql.py.

Comment: При том, что эта строка получает ответ из БД не в той кодировке, которая ожидается и пытаясь прочитать значение вместо понятных символов получает `'\xd1'`. В ожидаемой же кодировке символа с таким кодом не существует…

Comment: @qnub , а что же делать, чтобы исправить ошибку?

Comment: Либо изменить кодировку БД/таблицы/поля на `UTF-8` либо изменить параметры подключения к БД. Подробнее не скажу т.к. с `Access` не работал.

Comment: @qnub , почему я подверг сомнению ваше предположение - так это потому что при сохранении модуля sql.py вылетало окно с текстом

    Non-ASCII found, yet no encoding declared. Add a line like
      # -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
                to your file
     Choose OK to save this file as cp1251
     Edit your general options to silence this warning
             OK      Edit my file