# Не сохраняется файл при внесении в код символов русского алфавита

Tags: python, кодировка, python-2.x, idle

Поясните, пожалуйста, следующую ситуацию.
Питон 2.7.12. Среда разработки IDLE.

При создании нового файла, написании простейшей инструкции

```
print("Привет!")
```

и сохранении файла для его последующей компиляции, IDLE выдает одно и тоже сообщение с просьбой сохранить файл.

Нажав **ОК**, выбрав путь и подтвердив сохранение, пробую снова запустить файл и получаю то же сообщение.

Так до бесконечности, пока инструкция не будет заменена на

```
print("Hello!")
```

Протестует против русского алфавита? Почему?

Answer (score 1):

Выглядит как баг в IDLE (зависит от точной формулировки ошибки, которую он показывает). Если вы сохраните код в вопросе, используя другие средства, то при запуске вы должны получить [SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character ...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/160180/23044) Если исходный код содержит символы, которые не могут  быть представлены в `sys.getdefaultencoding()`кодировке (ascii на Питон 2), то следует явно объявлять используемую кодировку наверху файла, например: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` (если IDLE использует utf-8 кодировку при сохранении файлов в вашем окружении).

---

Не имеет отношения к вопросу, но стоит отметить: не используйте байт-строки для текста в Питоне—либо всё время `u''` префикс добавляйте к каждой строковой константе или наверху модуля добавьте `from __future__  import unicode_literals`.

Comment: Поправила, спасибо.

Comment: Однако, при коде

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__  import unicode_literals
print("Привет!")
name=raw_input("Введите имя: ")
print("Доброе утро", name)

Появляется новый баг:

Привет!
Введите имя: Ольга
(u'\u0414\u043e\u0431\u0440\u043e\u0435 \u0443\u0442\u0440\u043e', '\xce\xeb\xfc\xe3\xe0')

Comment: @Sam это уже другой вопрос. [Вот ответ на похожий вопрос на английском](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36891685/4279). Определитесь какую версию Питона вы хотите использовать (2 или 3)? Какой точный результат вы ожидали от `print("Доброе..", name)` на выбранной версии Питона? И опубликуйте как новый вопрос всю эту информацию (вместе с тем что сейчас получаете и полным, но минимальным примером кода).